# Text alignment in custom jQuery chart

Tags: jquery, alignment, css-tables

My page is coming along nicely and for the most part it looks fantastic.  The biggest issue I am having is that the rotated text in the column headers is mis-aligned.  How do I go about 'flooring' the text.  As you can see in the fiddle, it starts in the middle of the box and goes out of bounds. I would like to place it starting at the bottom of the box but have no idea how.

My rotate function works well and keeps the column width the way I need.

```
.r90 span {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    font-family:verdana;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 30px;
}
```

My css for the field elongates it.

```
th {
 height: 550px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/michaela_elise/CFNHP/

So where and how do I adjust the position of the text? I cannot figure it out for the life of me :P

Answer (score 0):

You only have to specify vertical alignment on the container:

```
.r90 {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

You can also add some padding to the left of the `<span>` elements, in order to leave some space between the containers and the text:

```
.r90 span {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CFNHP/32/).